# QGIS: Multifeature layer symbology and layer legend based on two separate attributes?

Tags: symbology, attribute-table

I'm quite new to QGIS, and I'm battling with something that seems like it should be really easy to do.

I have a polygon layer with hundreds of features, and I want to define the layer's symbology based on a certain attribute that has the value YES, NO or something else. So I want YES to be green, NO to be red and all the other values to be yellow. This is of course easy to do with categorized symbology.

BUT I want all the features to be shown in layer legend, and I want the legend text to represent the values of a second attribute, not the one that the symbology is based on. I could do this by categorizing the features based on this second attribute and just editing the symbols manually, but it's very inconvenient because I will be changing many of the YES/NO values in the future, so I would have to always edit the symbology too. I would like it to change automatically when I change the YES/NO attribute.

To simplify my problem. This is my data:

[image]

This is what I want the symbology (not the legend) to represent:

[image]

But this is what I want the layer to look like in QGIS:

[image]

I hope that clarifies what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Using data defined override for fill color would get you almost there (the polygon will get the right color but the legend will not...)